# Erro ao executar no editor de textos Atom

Tags: c++, variáveis, cmd, atom

O programa quando executo da esse seguinte erro http://prntscr.com/m42sl8 Sei que tem algo relacionado as variáveis, mas não sei o que colocar lá. Já fiz o processo do C:\MinGW\bin porém agora da esse problema, uso o Windows 10, qualquer ajuda agradeço.

Comment: Seja bem-vindo ao SOPT. Coloque a imagem diretamente na postagem, outra coisa, já tentou compilar direto pelo terminal? Notei que teu arquivo ta nomeado como `sem titulo`, pelo que deu pra entender, ele esta tentando executar isso como um comando, o que causa este erro na palavra "sem".

Comment: Realmente era o "sem" que estava causando problema, muito obrigado!!!!

Comment: Bom, se resolveu vou postar como resposta para que tu posa aceitar e ficar registrado para o futuro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Caso ainda não tenha tentado compilar pelo terminal/prompt, esta é uma boa forma de verificar os problemas da string de compilação. Teu arquivo esta nomeado como `sem titulo`, o erro esta na palavra "sem", pois ele esta tentando executar isto como um comando.

Para compilar via terminal/prompt use: `g++ -o nome_do_arquivo.cpp nome_do_exe.exe -Wall`, o `-Wall` vai ser útil para mostrar melhor qualquer erro no código, caso haja algum.